# ProtoBuf-Net , Open generic types serialization/ deserialization

Tags: generics, protobuf-net

I have the following Type:

```
Class Command<TData> : Base Where TData : I
```

In runtime this class is build (with specific TDATA) and Serialized.
I have 2 issues( I'm using V2 ):
1) When I'm adding this type to runtime modal :

```
var meta = this._modal.Add(type, false)
                             .Add(this.GetDMProperties(type).Select(p => p.Name)
                             .ToArray());
```

I get the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.ResolveProxies(Type type) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 952
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.FindWithoutAdd(Type type) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 118
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.ValueMember..ctor(RuntimeTypeModel model, Type parentType, Int32 fieldNumber, MemberInfo member, Type memberType, Type itemType, Type defaul
>   tType, DataFormat dataFormat, Object defaultValue) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\ValueMember.cs:line 75
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.AddField(Int32 fieldNumber, String memberName, Type itemType, Type defaultType, Object defaultValue) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobu
>   f-net\Meta\MetaType.cs:line 1165
>      at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.Add(String[] memberNames) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\MetaType.cs:line 1046

2) If i try to skip it at start up and try to do it on demand like below:

```
if (this._modal.CanSerializeContractType(objectType) == false)
            {
                this._modal.Add(objectType, false);
                this._modal.CompileInPlace();
            }
```

CanSerializeContractType returns true, but in practice only the base data is serialized.

My question is what is the practice of adding this type to modal without adding all permutations on design time if possible ?

Comment: Hi again; I've tried to repro your 2 issues (the exception, and the issue with `CanSerialize...`) - cannot reproduce either - [here's my test](http://pastie.org/3326027) - can you add any context to help me repro? Re the second, I wonder if `CanSerialize...` reports **false** initially, then you `Add` it, but you haven't added any members to serialize - is this the issue?

Comment: I added the code <script src='http://pastie.org/3327015.js'></script> CanSerialize returned true event though i didnt add the type.

Comment: that snippet does not allow me to reproduce the scenario - in particular the entire "Types" assembly. I could fake things, but then I can't guarantee that I'm looking at the same problem. Is there any way of cutting this down, maybe with just a single concrete class, that I can use to reproduce the issue?

Comment: [link](http://pastie.org/3327015) the code, the last is the types assembly.if there is anything else i can do to help you repro,please let me know

Comment: k; I have a repro for that now, thanks - it relates to open generic types (`type == T`, for no specific `T`). I'll see what I can do (fixing that it easy - I mean more: thinking of a way to address the scenario)

Comment: Thanks for you support and library, BTW is the project home page is the place to get updates on the project updates ?

Comment: I tend to trickle updates via Nuget, or announce major releases on my blog.

Comment: We're hitting the same NullReferenceException in ResolveProxies, apparently protobuf-net is choking on types that don't have a 'FullName' property. Do you have plans to release a fix any time soon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will have to investigate the first; sounds like an odd edge case bug. However, your second point ties into a conversation I had a short while ago - with the conclusion that I will add an event that is fired when a type is first seen. You would then have the opportunity *during* the event of configuring the type. In theory: simple; I just need to implement it. I will "bump" this forwards on my list of things...

Side note: unless you are only working inside a single AppDomain and not writing to disk or sending over the network or between processes, you **must** make sure you can reliably add properties/sun-types with the same keys. Or more specifically: eithrr your GetDMaproperties method (not shown) needs some kind of fixed order, or you need an OrderBy in the LINQ. Also; that is brittle - if anyone adds/removes/renames a property, the keys will change.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.i was just wondering if the above is not feasible without adding the new event ? , second are the properties tags must be unique or they behave as DataMember order?

Comment: @eyan well, you could decorate with attributes; but other than that... Not currently. Re "second" - must be unique per type

Comment: Thanks,is there a way to achieve Version tolerance ? can you direct to a blog or other means which explains some "advance" usage with the serializer ? (AsReference....). thanks again.

Comment: @eyan since protobuf doesn't store field names, for version tolerance I strongly recommend: store the key/name map somewhere